# How can I reload a react js component after filtering data

Tags: javascript, filter, server-side-rendering, use-effect, use-state

I will appreciate your help with my project.

I created button filters for a component that displays list of courses in a nextjs project. When I click on a button it filters the courses but when I refresh the page it gives me the error below:

./pages/index.js
Module parse failed: Identifier 'courses1' has already been declared (15:15)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

**Please see code below.**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import CourseCard from "../components/cards/CourseCard";
import { Button } from 'antd'


const Index = ({ courses }) => {



const allTopics = ['All', ...new Set(courses.map(courses => courses.topic))]



const [courses, setCourses] = useState(courses)
const [buttons, setButtons] = useState(allTopics)


  const filter = (button) => {

    if (button === 'All') {
        setCourses(courses)
    }

    const filteredData = courses.filter(courses => courses.topic === button)
    setCourses(filteredData)
 
}




return (
    <>
        <h1 className="jumbotron p-5 text-center bg-primary text-white square">OEP</h1>
        <div className="container-fluid">

            <div>
                {
                    buttons.map((topic, i) => {
                        return <Button onClick={() => filter(topic)} className="btn ms-2">{topic}</Button>
                    })
                }
            </div>

            <div className="row">

                {courses.map((course) => <div key={course._id} className="col-md-4">
                    <CourseCard course={course} />
                </div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)
};



export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${process.env.API}/courses`);
    return {
        props: {
            courses: data,


        },
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

The constant `courses` you declared (in line 15) already existed. It was destructured from the parameters of `Index`. Try to change the name of one of these 2 variables.

Comment: Many Thanks @hamza13, I changed the name and it worked.